# Magento 2 product price including tax

Tags: magento2, product, price, tax, edit

How to set price including tax in product admin edit view?

In **Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax** I set all options to "Incuding tax" but still I can't see **[Inc.Tax]**. Anyone know how to set it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try re-index and flush cache?

Comment: Yes, I did but still there is no [Inc. Tax] label.